# How to avoid adding double quotes to the metadata keywords in PDF file using iTextSharp in C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, metadata, xmp

Using the iTextSharp Library I'm able to insert metadata in a PDF file using the various Schemas.

The keywords in the keywords metadata are for my purposes delimited by a comma and enclosed in double quotes.  Once the script I've written runs, the keywords are enclosed in triple quotes.

Any ideas on how to avoid this or any advice on working with XMP?

Example of required metadata : `"keyword1","keyword2","keyword3"`

Example of current metadata : `"""keyword1"",""keyword2"",""keyword3"""`

Coding:

```
string _keywords = meta_line.Split(',')[1] + ","
                             + meta_line.Split(',')[2] + ","
                             + meta_line.Split(',')[3] + ","
                             + meta_line.Split(',')[4] + ","
                             + meta_line.Split(',')[5] + ","
                             + meta_line.Split(',')[6] + ","
                             + meta_line.Split(',')[7];
            _keywords = _keywords.Replace('~', ',');

            Console.WriteLine(metaFile);

            foreach (string inputFile in Directory.GetFiles(source, "*.pdf", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            {
                if (Path.GetFileName(metaFile) == Path.GetFileName(inputFile))
                {
                    string outputFile = source + @"\output\" + Path.GetFileName(inputFile);
                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFile);

                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                    {

                        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);
                        Dictionary<String, String> info = reader.Info;
                        stamper.MoreInfo = info;

                        PdfWriter writer = stamper.Writer;

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];

                        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(buffer, true);
                        try
                        {
                            iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp.XmpSchema dc = new iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp.DublinCoreSchema();

                            dc.SetProperty(iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp.DublinCoreSchema.TITLE, new iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp.LangAlt(_title));

                            iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp.XmpArray subject = new iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp.XmpArray(iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp.XmpArray.ORDERED);
                            subject.Add(_subject);
                            dc.SetProperty(iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp.DublinCoreSchema.SUBJECT, subject);

                            iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp.XmpArray author = new iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp.XmpArray(iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp.XmpArray.ORDERED);
                            author.Add(_author);
                            dc.SetProperty(iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp.DublinCoreSchema.CREATOR, author);

                            PdfSchemaAdvanced pdf = new PdfSchemaAdvanced();

                            pdf.AddKeywords(_keywords);


                            iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp.XmpWriter xmp = new iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp.XmpWriter(ms);
                            xmp.AddRdfDescription(dc);
                            xmp.AddRdfDescription(pdf);
                            xmp.Close();

                            int bufsize = buffer.Length;
                            int bufcount = 0;
                            foreach (byte b in buffer)
                            {
                                if (b == 0) break;
                                bufcount++;
                            }
                            System.IO.MemoryStream ms2 = new System.IO.MemoryStream(buffer, 0, bufcount);
                            buffer = ms2.ToArray();

                            foreach (char buff in buffer)
                            {
                                Console.Write(buff);
                            }
                            writer.XmpMetadata = buffer;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw ex;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            ms.Close();
                            ms.Dispose();
                        }

                        stamper.Close();
                     // writer.Close();

                    }

                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
```

The below method didn't add any metadata - not sure why (point 3 in the comments):

```
iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp.XmpArray keywords = new     iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp.XmpArray(iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp.XmpArray.ORDERED);
                            keywords.Add("keyword1");
                            keywords.Add("keyword2");
                            keywords.Add("keyword3");


                            pdf.SetProperty(iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp.PdfSchema.KEYWORDS, keywords);
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking because you haven't provided enough information for us to know what you're doing. Please show us how you're declaring the data, and how you are adding it. If what you displayed is the _how_, then also show us where you define `_keywords`.

Comment: I realise that I'm passing '_keyword' as a string but can't find another method (that works) to add these keywords.  There is another method of the PDFschema class that passes a <string> list but the required metadata was not generated.

Comment: what does `_keywords` variable contain? does it have "bare" words, or already with quotes? I mean, have you tried setting a breakpoint at `pdf.AddKeywords(_keywords);` and checking what exactly does that function receive to process?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Presently, they are purely alpha numeric characters.

Comment: @Taniq When there is a problem that you can't figure out, often times it's because something you assume is true is not. We see you creating `_keywords` now, but you're using a new variable `metaline` which you haven't defined. You should double check that there are no additional quotes in the data you are passing in. Right now, there's no way for us to know based upon what you provided other than what you've said. Check again. Code doesn't lie, but sometimes comments and developers are wrong.

Comment: The Keywords are read line by line from a CSV file.  This list describes the obstacles I've tried overcoming when adding this metadata in the required format: 1. Passing ''_keywords'' as is results in the metadata being enclosed in double quotes and ''_keywords'' are then considered as a single keyword in the metadata.  2.  I then tried to enclose each keyword with double quotes but this adds another double quote to the front and back of the metadata once passed. 3.  I tried using an XMParray to store the keywords but it doesn't show in the metadata (see edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I currently don't have the newest iTextSharp version. I have a itextsharp 5.1.1.0. It does not contain `PdfSchemaAdvanced` class, but it has `PdfSchema` and its base class `XmpSchema`. I bet the `PdfSchemaAdvanced` in your lib also derives from `XmpSchema`.

The `PdfSchema.AddKeyword` only does one thing:

```
base["pdf:Keywords"] = keywords;
```

and `XmpSchema.[].set` in turn does:

```
base[key] = XmpSchema.Escape(value);
```

so it's very clear that the value is being, well, 'Escaped', to ensure that special characters are not interfering with the storage format.

Now, the `Escape` function, what what I see, performs simple character-by-character scanning and performs substitutions:

```
" -> &quot;
& -> &amp;
' -> &apos;
< -> &lt;
> -> &gt;
```

and that's all. Seems like a typical html-entites processing. At least in my version of the library. So, it would not duplicate the quotes, just change their encoding.

Then, `AddRdfDescription` seems to simply iterate over the stored keys and just wraps them in tags with no furhter processing. So, it'd emit something like that:

```
Escaped"Contents&OfThis"Key
```

as:

```
<pdf:Keywords>Escaped&quot;Contents&amp;OfThis&quot;Key</pdf:Keywords>
```

Aside from the `AddKeywords` method, you should also see `AddProperty` method. It acts similarly to add-keywords except for the fact that it receives `key` and **does not Escape()** its input value.

So, if you are **perfectly sure** that your `_keywords` are formatted properly, you might try:

```
AddProperty("pdf:Keywords", _keywords)
```

but I **discourage** you from doing that. At least in my version of itextsharp, the library seems to properly process the 'keywords' and format it safely as RDF.

Heh, you may also try using the `PdfSchema` class that I just checked instead of the `Advanced` one. I bet it still is present in the library.

But, in general, I think the problem lies elsewhere.

Double or triple-check the contents of _keywords variable **and** then also check the binary contents of the generated PDF. Look into it with some hexeditor or simple plain-text editor like Notepad and look for the `<pdf:Keywords>` tag. Check what it actually contains. It might be all OK and it might be your pdf-metadata-reader that adds those quotes.

Comment: PDFSchemaAdvanced was extended from PDFschema. I extended the PDFschema class in an attempt to force the double quotes to enclose each keyword... Didn't work.

Comment: I'm a novice coder, this seems very informative and probably very useful.